# GNU screen, tmux, dvtm - none are working as ordinary user on OVH VPS

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, tmux

I bought cheapest vps for teamspeak hosting and I have strange issues with demonizing it's process. None of screen tmux and dvtm work for ordinary user, but they work witout a charm for root. As far as i know running server apps from root is not very wise.

No errors are generated, I could not find any logs.

screen -> instant [screen is terminating]
dvtm -> instant hang, I need to reconnect ssh
tmux -> this imageshack.us/photo/my-images/39/i59a.png/

Comment: Everything in a home network setting is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on [SF]. Your question *might* fit at another site of the [SE] network (consider [SU] and [unix.se] in particular), but please check their respective FAQs and archives before posting there.

Comment: Using `screen` *et al* is not a way to "demonize" a process.

Answer (score 1):

The ts3StartScript "demonizes" itself. No screen or nohup required.